# Get memory location and space associated to process using processId

Tags: windows, task-manager, wmic

I want to get the memory information(address and size) of a process in Ram using process id. I tried WMIC and task manager they provide only the memory used by the process at current time. Could anyone please let me know how to get this information from windows OS.

Comment: Is [that](http://www.cheatengine.org/) what you want?

Comment: Some sort of, but this is for game, but I actually wants to read the ram memory.